# Weir to vent distance and venting options - IPC 2015

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

I have a new bathroom which plumbs the shower into the main stack via a 2” PVC pipe.
My understanding is that the distance from the trap weir to a (in this case wet) vent can be up to 8”.

My shower weir-to-vent distance is about 7'9", properly graded at 1/4” per foot, so it would appear I am in the clear as far as siphoning and any vent issues go.  However, I am hearing different takes on whether my long drain constitutes a trap arm which should not be more than 5’ in length.

[image]

Just in case, I installed a separate extra vent (pointed to in red) to the right of the p-trap, that goes through the wall in the shower and into the attic, where it terminates in a AAV (Studor valve), which in itself is legal per my local regulations (and IPC 2015).

[image: extra vent1]

[image: extra vent2]

[image: extra vent3]

My questions:

1. Is my sub-8-foot weir-to-vent plumbing to code as far as IPC 2015?
2. If it is not, will my extra vent be an IPC 2015-permissible way to vent the shower?
3. I don’t like the idea of having metal straps rubbing against the PVC piping, so I am inserting rubber between them (see example photo).  Is there anything wrong with that?
   [image: rubber gasket]

Comment: Anyone?  Bueller?

Answer (score 1):

Your vent configuration is fine, if unusual.

Not sure about the rubber bushing.  Seems like you are inventing a solution to metal straps severing PVC pipes.  I've never noticed an epidemic of metal straps severing PVC.  If you don't want to use the strap, **replace it with a J-hook.**  They are sold at any plumbing supplier.

Comment: Jeff, much appreciate the response.  For my own understanding, is there something I am missing in the whole 5ft vs 8ft trap arm length for 2" waste lines?  In what case is one vs the other applicable?

Comment: UPC has a table specifying a max trap arm of 5-feet for a 2" drain.  My read of your post is that you are under IPC.

Comment: Looks like there are differentiations between the code - 
UPC states 5' max trap to vent, while IPC 2015 states 8' max trap to vent.
I am in an IPC 2015 land, so my 7'9" trap arm length should be ok.  I thought I was going crazy and misunderstanding definitions within the same code, but the codes are just different.